# Canon Pixma G2000 printer driver for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printer, canon-pixma, print-drivers

How to install Canon G2000 printer driver on Ubuntu?

I can't find any driver for Linux on Canon official website.

The printer is totally unable to work on ubuntu without a driver, any ideas?

Comment: I did a pretty thorough search and couldn't find any evidence that Canon or any third party has Linux drivers for this model.  You could try contacting Canon tech support for advice.  It's possible that the driver for a different model will be close enough to work.  Search the various Linux and Ubuntu forums for reports of success, or you could experiment with the available drivers in CUPS to see if one works.  I found only a few related threads and there was no reported success.

Comment: I had contact Canon support before but they told me to buy a Canon G4000, because currently in G serial only G4000 support Linux. Wtf?

I regret that why I do not do research before buying :(

Answer (score 1):

You can get this printer working by installing gutenprint for linux. I wrote 
 [detailed instructions on my blog](http://blog.droidzone.in/2017/08/07/how-to-install-printers-for-canon-pixma-g2000-on-ubuntu/).

The options for a person trying to install Canon's G1000 and G2000 are limited to the following:

1. Compile and install gutenprint. Gutenprint, formerly named Gimp-Print, is a suite of printer drivers for linux. It works just like native drivers and supports cups based printing.
2. Buy a third party linux printing driver and utility, called Turboprint. It too has excellent support. An added bonus is a GUI for checking printer spooling, and configuring varied options like Paper type, resolution etc. The cost of an individual license is upwards of $34.

If you decide to go with the first solution, the steps include the following. My system is a Ubuntu Xenial 64bit.

First you need some developmental headers. So add to your /etc/apt/sources.list, the following lines if you dont have them. Modify these according to your version of Linux(Debian/Ubuntu):

```
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Update your sources and install the build dependencies:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get build-dep cups-common gimp-gutenprint libgutenprint-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now download the source release package for gutenberg (version >=5.2.13) from [Sourceforge](http://blog.droidzone.in/2017/08/07/how-to-install-printers-for-canon-pixma-g2000-on-ubuntu/).

```
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/files/gutenprint-5.2/5.2.13/gutenprint-5.2.13.tar.bz2/download
tar xvf download
cd gutenprint-5.2.13
```

Alternately clone the git repo.

```
git clone https://git.code.sf.net/p/gimp-print/source gimp-print-source
cd gimp-print-source
```

Now configure, make and install.

```
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Source: [My blog post](http://blog.droidzone.in/2017/08/07/how-to-install-printers-for-canon-pixma-g2000-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

Setup to download and Installation [Canon PIXMA G2000](https://canonprint-drivers.com/canon-pixma-g2000-series-driver/)

Download / Installation Procedures for Windows

1. Click the link, select [ Save ], specify "Save As", then click [ Save ] to download the file.
2. The downloaded file will be saved in the specified place in the self-extracting form (.exe format ).
3. Double-click the downloaded .exe file. It will be decompressed and the Setup screen will be displayed. Follow the instructions to install the software and perform the necessary settings.

Download / Installation Procedures For Mac

1. Download the file. For the location where the file is saved, check the computer settings.
2. Double-click the downloaded file and mount it on the Disk Image.
3. Double-click the mounted Disk Image.
4. Double-click the “Setup” file to launch the setup screen. By following the instructions on the screen, install the software and do the connection settings for your printer.